# Contains for List of Pair

Tags: java, collections

```
  List<Pair<String, String> > lp = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String> >();
  lp.add(new Pair("1", "2"));
```

How should I check if the list lp contains 1 and 2 i.e the Pair ("1", "2").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Pair` class needs to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` and you're all set.  `List.contains()` is implemented in terms of the type's `equals()` method.  See the [API for `List.contains()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).  (Edited a bit to address comments from @maaartinus, whose answer you should read b/c the observations are solid, and it's a bit ridiculous for me to fold them in here.  As maaartinus points out, a best-practice here would be to avoid error-prone manual definitions for equals and hashcode, and instead build on Guava's helper functions for [nullable equals](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#equal%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) and [hashCode for n objects](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#hashCode%28java.lang.Object...%29)).

```
final class Pair<T> {

   final T left;
   final T right;

   public Pair(T left, T right)
   {
     if (left == null || right == null) { 
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("left and right must be non-null!");
     }
     this.left = left;
     this.right = right;
   }

   public boolean equals(Object o)
   {
     // see @maaartinus answer
     if (! (o instanceof Pair)) { return false; }
     Pair p = (Pair)o;
     return left.equals(p.left) && right.equals(p.right);
   } 

   public int hashCode()
   {
      return 7 * left.hashCode() + 13 * right.hashCode();
   } 
}
```

With suitable `equals()`, you can now do:

```
  lp.add(new Pair("1", "2"));
  assert lp.contains(new Pair("1","2"));
```

Responding to the comments below, perhaps it would be good to include a good reference for "Why do I need to implement `hashCode()`?"

- JavaPractices.com — [Implementing `equals()`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) — "if you override equals, you must override hashCode"
- [`Object.equals()` contract as defined in the API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java/27609#27609)

Comment: Good answer.  I think I pushed you over 3000.  Cool.

Comment: equals() is the key point, hashCode() has nothing with ArrayList. but we need to follow "Always override hashCode when you override equals".

Comment: You're right that `equals()` is the point, but so many folks make the mistake of doing one and not the other, so I like to treat the two atomically.

Comment: This answer is incorrect (or at least misleading). With null members allowed, `equals` is not reflexive and `hashCode` throws (for details see my answer). With null members forbidden, the null tests in `equals` are useless.

Comment: @maaartinus:  Yes.  IMHO, Pair makes the most sense with null members forbidden, so provided such a constructor.  Didn't fix the rest as your answer deserves the credit...

Comment: Nice. One more thing: There are missing brackets around instanceof and I'd drop the null tests in `equals`.

Comment: I can't make either of these answer work.  Can you please help?

Comment: Sure... but I've got no idea, what's your problem. I'm using a Pair quite similar to what I've wrote in my answer (just a bit more complicated, as there's an AbstractPair with a mutable and an immutable subclasses), so I'm quite sure it works.

Comment: @Bill: Can you provide an error or exception trace, and we can help.

Comment: I need the Button button = new Button() piece ;)  I can't figure out the implementation of the class.  I have no doubt it works as described.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation in the answer by andersoj

```
 return left != null && right != null && left.equals(p.left) && right.equals(p.right);
```

is wrong: The null tests clearly suggest that null is a legal value for left and right. So there are at least two problems there:

- `new Pair(null, null).hashCode()` throws NPE
- `new Pair(null, null)` does NOT equal to itself!

Have a look at [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) class Objects for a correct implementation. Use it or write a static helper methods like

```
public static boolean equal(Object a, Object b) {
    return a==b || a!=null && a.equals(b);
}
public static int hashCode(Object a) {
    return a==null ? 0 : a.hashCode();
}
```

and always use them.

***Never ever write `equals` containing a null test.***

It's to easy to blow it, and nobody noticed it. Using the Helper, it's trivial to get it right:

```
public boolean equals(Object o)  {
    if (!(o instanceof Pair)) return false;
    Pair p = (Pair) o;
    return Helper.equals(left, p.left) && Helper.equals(right, p.right);
} 

public int hashCode() {
    return 7 * Helper.hashCode(left) + 13 * Helper.hashCode(right);
}
```

Of course, forbidding nulls in the constructor is an option, too.

Comment: +1: You're right, and I certainly didn't do due diligence in making it perfect.  Thanks for making sure it's right.  If I had +2 to offer, I'd give it for the "Use Guava" direction.

Comment: Thank you.... after having got it wrong twice, I wrote the Helper and forbid myself doing it manually.

Comment: I can't make either of these answers work.  Can you please help?  What the heck is Helper, etc.

Comment: Helper is a helper class (what else?) implementing the methods `equal(Object a, Object b)` and `hashCode(Object a)` as given above.